How to create an executable for windows from C source that includes openssl
I'm trying to create a Windows executable from C and I want to include openssl in it, so that the system that will run it, won't need to have openssl installed.
I'm compiling on a Windows machine, using gcc.
To get my program to work, I compiled incuding the openssl headers and linked with the flags -lcrypto -lssl but the resulting executable won't run on another Windows PC, because it doesn't find the openssl. (The full error says that libcrypto-1_1-x64__.dll was not found).
Now I got hold of openssl .a files, that are supposed to be the static version of the library, in order to include them. I tried some prebuilt binaries found online and I also tried to build them from source.
Various version that tried to link to them with -L<directory> or -Bstatic would build, but still gave the same error on the other machine. The executable was also the same size.
I also tried not linking with the -l flag, and included the two .a files (libcrypto.a and libssl.a) in the compilation, listing them along the other .o files. The compilation succeded and the program runs, but it is still the same size and it still wouldn't run on the other machine.
Can someone identify my issue?
